# GPG Input/Output Error

Tags: maven, gnupg

```
gpg: signing error: Input/output error
```

When I tried to deploy my maven project using the command `mvn deploy -DperformRelease=true` and I got to the step where I had to enter my GPG passphrase I got the above error. I thought this was because I mistyped the passphrase, but after multiple attempts I kept getting the same error. I then updated my GPG installation to the most recent modern version, but still the same error.

Then I tried to create a new key, but when I got to the step where I had to create the password I got this error:

```
gpg: agent_genkey failed: Input/output error
Key generation failed: Input/output error
```

Also an input/output error. Interestingly enough, I believe that in both cases I had this error spit out 2 lines above those errors:

```
gpg: AllowSetForegroundWindow(16252) failed: Access is denied.
```

Whether that is related, I don't know. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with gpg on Windows (Gpg4win). I fixed it by uninstalling Gpg4win and installing Gpg4win-Vanilla (the most lightweight version of Gpg4win): https://www.gpg4win.org/download.html